# Gson error: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

My json:

```
{"code":200,"data":[{"xxx":"xxx","yyy":1234,"zzz":"56789"},{...}]}
```

I need Gson to take the **data** part in the shape of [{...}] and put it to simple `String`. But Gson keeps trying to parse it as an array and throws this `JsonSyntaxException`. Is it possible to get the result as I want it?

Gson fromJson call:

```
ParsedResponse parsedResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ParsedResponse.class);
```

ParsedResponse class:

```
public class ParsedResponse {

    @SerializedName("code")
    private int code;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private String data;

    private int statusCode;

    // getters, setters
}
```

**EDIT**:
The system works when I have {...} in data, so why couldn't it work with [{...}]? I just need Gson to take the string [{...}] and put it to String variable.

Comment: Well, that is an array that you are trying to parse into String

Comment: Yes, it works ok with {...} in data, so why couldn't it work with [{...}]?

Comment: In JSON [] (Square brackets) represents an array -So, [{"xxx":"xxx","yyy":1234,"zzz":"56789"},{...}] is an array of Strings

Comment: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

Comment: Define and register a new TypeAdapter

Comment: **Correction - array of objects

Comment: read gson [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no. Just put into Array and then convert to what you need. 
Other approach is to see if you can over-ride some parser implementation of GSON.
Or write your own JSON to reflection library. :-).

*** Or, just write your own JSON parsing as your data format might be well-known to you and simply enough. :-)

Comment: I've found a solution. What about to use Object data instead of String data in ParsedResponse class? Gson is ok with it and all I need is to change getter and return data.toString()